iopub data rate exceeded in jupyter notebook
I realize this is a duplicate, but the answers posted aren't helping me
duplicate: IOPub data rate exceeded in Jupyter notebook (when viewing image)
I'm on a mac. When using a sage worksheet (it's downloaded as an app, but opens in my web browser) I am trying to run a (ipynb) program that works fine for small numbers, but produces a tonnnnn of output [ using print(variable) ]. I'm getting an error that says to avoid crashing, the program has stopped --- That it is capped at 1 Mbps. I understand that I need to increase the data rate allowance, but do not understand (for the life of me) how to do so.
One solution says to type

jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10

but I don't understand where this goes...
When I type this into my jupyter/sagews I get an error about syntax
When I type this into 'terminal' directly, I get an error that says 'zsh: command not found: jupyter-lab'
Another mac user says they searched Finder for 'iopub_data_rate_limit', up popped a file named 'channels.py,' that he was able to manually change the limit from 1000000 to whatever he liked within the file. When I search for 'iopub_data_rate_limit' or 'channels.py' in finder, nothing comes up.
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The Jupyter server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--ServerApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
ServerApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
ServerApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)


This can depend on how you are starting your Jupyter notebook. The command jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10 can be executed from your command line to launch the jupyter notebook for you to start working. You probably need also something like jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10 my_notebook.ipynb. All command line options are available here
